# Prevent Fragment from Jumping to Top of Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase

I'm building a chat app in Android using Firebase and I've ran into an annoying issue that I'm not sure how to fix. Any time I press the send button to send the message the Recyclerview that is housed in my fragment "jumps" to the top instead of staying fixed at the last message sent. I'm assuming it has to do with setting the adapter after calling my ValueEventListener, but I'm not sure how to avoid this. Any suggestions?

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ChatFragment";

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FragmentChatBinding binding;
    private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessageAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ChatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate layout
        binding = FragmentChatBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        // store root view
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_message_list);

        // get instance of firebase database node "message"
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message");

        binding.buttonChatboxSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessageToDb();
            }
        });

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        binding.recyclerviewMessageList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        setChatListener();

        // return root view
        return view;
    }


    /*
    Sets listener for chat fragment
     */
    private void setChatListener() {
        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                messageArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    messageArrayList.add(message);
                }
                adapter = new MessageAdapter(messageArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(listener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your LinearLayoutManager to the following:

```
LinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thank you!